# Detecting Missing Modules Dynamically (Python)

Tags: python, module, error-detection

When working on bigger projects, I'm very keen on error detection and handling. I'm using some modules that the user may or may not have installed, so I need to account for this possibility.

I'd like to know of a way to detect what modules are missing while attempting to import them. Currently, I have a set of try/except blocks watching for ImportErrors and appending the names of the error-producing modules to a list.

Current Code:

```
errors = []
try:
    import socket
except ImportError:
    errors.append('socket')
    pass
try:
    import shutil
except ImportError:
    errors.append('shutil')
try:
    import urllib
except ImportError:
    errors.append('urllib')
    pass
if len(errors) > 0:
    print colors.red + '[!] ' + colors.end + 'Error: The Following Module(s) Encountered Error(s): \n'
    for i in range(len(errors)):
        print '\t' + errors[i]
    print colors.blue + '\n[*] ' + colors.end + 'Please Install/Reinstall the Listed Modules'
    quit()
```

This method seems to work just fine, but I'd like a way that will take up less overall room. The main reason for using this multi-try/except block method is that I need to detect which module had trouble importing.

Comment: Why not use [proper packaging](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), so that `pip` can take care of installing dependencies? That way you move the responsibility for dependency management *out* of your code and don't have to worry about how to handle the errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
import importlib

moduleNames = ['socket', 'shutil', 'urllib']

missingModuleNames = []

for moduleName in moduleNames:
    try:
        importlib.import_module (moduleName)
    except:
        missingModuleNames.append (moduleName)

print (missingModuleNames)
```